# How do give every circle a random color in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, draw

In this program, I want a bigger movable circle and many multi-colored smaller circles. However, when I run the program all of the smaller circles are all the same color and I cannot figure out how to randomly give each of them a different color. How do I fix this?

```
import pygame as pg
import random as rd

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

p_1_x = 200
p_1_y = 200
p_1_change_x = 0

def p_1(x, y):
    player_1 = pg.draw.circle(screen, (2, 2, 0), (x, y), 15)


locations = []
small_color = []

for i in range(50):
    red = rd.randint(0, 220)
    blue = rd.randint(0, 220)
    green = rd.randint(0, 220)
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    locations.append((x, y))
    small_color.append((red, blue, green))


while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                p_1_change_x = 1
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                p_1_change_x = -1

        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT or pg.K_LEFT:
                p_1_change_x = 0

    p_1_x += p_1_change_x

    p_1(p_1_x, p_1_y)
    for locate in locations:
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (small_color[i]), locate, 5)

    pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Beside each answers there is a ✔ tick, You can accept an answer and approve it if it works for you by ✅ checking the tick, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure you import `random` library at the first line:

```
import random as rd
```

Here is a simple function, which generate random color:

```
def random_color():
    r = rd.randint(0, 255)
    g = rd.randint(0, 255)
    b = rd.randint(0, 255)
    return (r, g, b)
```

so you can call it when ever you need to:

```
    color = random_color()
    draw.circle(screen, color, (x, y), SIZE)
```

### Github repo

I make a repo in the GitHub and did some changes,
Dots are colorful, new dot gets random color and the ball gets bigger whenever eats a dot.

[image]

https://github.com/peymanmajidi/Ball-And-Dots-Game__Pygame

Answer (score 2):

In the main loop, you're using `i` which never changes. Use **enumerate** to return an index while looping through the locations collection.

Try this code:

```
for i,locate in enumerate(locations):
    pg.draw.circle(screen, (small_color[i]), locate, 5)
```